# Google script: Retrieve data from textbox

Tags: textbox, google-apps-script, buttonclick

I am trying to use Google App Script for the first time and want to get data out of a textbox in on a button click (Into variable TC in the second function). I have tried to follow both from Google and online but it seems like all the functions hey use have been decommissioned. Can anyone give me some guidance on this, I don't have any experience with UIs and have been working at this project for several hours.

See simplified code below.

Thank you,

John

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Richardson-Dushmann Calculator');

  var Temperature  = app.createTextBox().setName("Temperature");

  var button = app.createButton('Calculate').setId('Calculate');
  var handler = button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction"));

  var inputGrid = app.createGrid(1, 3);
  var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();  

      inputGrid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('T = '));
      inputGrid.setWidget(0, 1, Temperature);
      inputGrid.setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel(' \xB0C'));

      mypanel.add(inputGrid);
      mypanel.add(button);

  app.add(mypanel);
  return app;

}

function handlerFunction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var TC = e.parameter.Temperature;

   return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the handler what widget value should be transmitted to the function.

You could add the textBox but it's a good practice to add the highest level parent widget in case you need other values later on.

Use `handler.addCallBackElement(widget)` to achieve that, [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/server-handler).

EDIT following comment :

full code

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Richardson-Dushmann Calculator');

  var Temperature  = app.createTextBox().setName("Temperature");

  var inputGrid = app.createGrid(1, 3);
  var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();  

  var button = app.createButton('Calculate').setId('Calculate');
  var handler = button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction").addCallbackElement(mypanel))


      inputGrid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('T = '));
      inputGrid.setWidget(0, 1, Temperature);
      inputGrid.setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel(' \xB0C'));

      mypanel.add(inputGrid);
      mypanel.add(button);

  app.add(mypanel);
  return app;

}

function handlerFunction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var TC = e.parameter.Temperature;

   return app.add(app.createLabel(e.parameter.Temperature));// add the returned value in the app to check it comes back in the handler
 }
```

[test here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbywuBFjrJXADftYyiLqSAPI4fIW_CqrJ8YHrQXETt2E9WSlLwv5/exec)

Comment: I tried doing this and it did not work. Even copy-pasting the code snippet under addCallbackElement in the Google documentation did not work.

Comment: see edit please... you probably forgot to change version